# Do I have to file taxes for NC if I live in SC and my HQ is in SC but I work out of office in NC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax

I was wondering if I have to file my taxes for NC if I work out of an office in NC but my HQ is in SC and I live in SC?

I have filed my NC tax the previous 2 years and of course I owe NC money back and SC is supposed to credit me for those. I just want to make sure I am doing this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do. You earn money in NC, so that's where it is going to be taxed first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must file North Carolina AND South Carolina income tax.

If you live in one state and work in another, the income is potentially taxed twice. Most states give a credit for taxes paid to the other state. Often you pay the tax in the state where you worked, and then if the tax rate in the state where you live is higher, you pay the difference. But the details depend on the tax laws of the two states involved. I'm not an expert on either Carolina's tax laws. Start by getting the forms and instructions from both states and see what they say. Or if you're using tax software, see if it handles this case. If someone else on here knows the specifics of the tax laws for the Carolinas, I gladly yield. :-)

Many states establish "reciprocity agreements" with other states, usually the neighboring states, that generally say that if the state you live in and the state you work in are both party to the agreement, then you only pay tax in the state you live in. This simplifies things a lot. Unfortunately, neither North Carolina nor South Carolina have such agreements with each other or with any other state.

Comment: +1, could have been perfect if you actually linked to the state forms:) But who am I to complain, I wrote a single line :-D